# CGFloat値の小数点以下を含む数値を整数にし、また小数点を含む数値に戻したい。

Tags: swift, ios

２点間の与えられた始点と終点の間に連続した点を置く為に、ブレゼンハムのアルゴリズムを使用したいのですが、座標(x,y)がCGFloat値で小数点以下の数値があります。
そこも含めて一旦、整数値Intにし計算する必要があると思うのですが、欲しいのは最終的に小数点を含むCGFloat値である為、どの様にSwiftで小数点→整数→小数点にするのが効率よく記述できますでしょうか。ブレゼンハムのコード自体は以下の様にしたいと考えています。宜しくお願い致します。

```
func getPoints(p0: CGPoint, p1: CGPoint) -> [CGPoint] {
        var points = [CGPoint]()
        var x0: Int = Int(p0.x)
        var y0: Int = Int(p0.y)
        let x1: Int = Int(p1.x)
        let y1: Int = Int(p1.y)
        let dx: Int = Int(abs(p1.x - p0.x)) // DeltaX
        let dy: Int = Int(abs(p1.y - p0.y)) // DeltaY
        let sx: Int = (p1.x>p0.x) ? 1 : -1 // StepX
        let sy: Int = (p1.y>p0.y) ? 1 : -1 // StepT
        var err = dx - dy
        while true {
            if x0 >= 0, y0 >= 0 { points.append(CGPoint(x: x0, y: y0)) }
            if x0 == x1, y0 == y1 { break }
            let e2 = 2*err
            if e2 > -dy {
                err -= dy
                x0 += sx
            }
            if e2 < dx {
                err += dx
                y0 += sy
            }
        }
        return points
    }
```

Comment: CGFloatをIntにせずにCGFloatのまま計算していいと思いますが、何か問題があったのでしょうか？

Comment: ありがとうございます。IntをCGFloatに変更し、実行してみたところ、実行時間が恐ろしくかかってしまうものとなりました。
let sx: CGFloat = (p1.x>p0.x) ? 1 : -1 // StepX
let sy: CGFloat = (p1.y>p0.y) ? 1 : -1 // StepT
を変更し、小数点も扱えるように0.1 : -0.1
としたところ、同じ桁の小数点では結果が早く返ってくるものの、x0=576.5,x1=576.0という様な数値を扱いたい場合、整数に直した方がいいものかと思ったのですが如何なのでしょうか。

Comment: `CGFloat`で示される２点間を直線で描画したいだけなら`BezierPath`の利用を検討しても良い気がします

Answer (score 0, accepted):

浮動小数点数（`CGFloat`）と整数（`Int`）の変換ではなく、丸め処理（`rounded()`）で小数点以下を切り捨てたほうが、処理時間を短縮できるという結果になりました。

```
import Foundation

// 質問で提示された、CGFloatとInt間の変換を伴う処理
func getPointsA(p0: CGPoint, p1: CGPoint) -> [CGPoint] {
    var points = [CGPoint]()
    var x0: Int = Int(p0.x)
    var y0: Int = Int(p0.y)
    let x1: Int = Int(p1.x)
    let y1: Int = Int(p1.y)
    let dx: Int = Int(abs(p1.x - p0.x))
    let dy: Int = Int(abs(p1.y - p0.y))
    let sx: Int = (p1.x > p0.x) ? 1 : -1
    let sy: Int = (p1.y > p0.y) ? 1 : -1
    var err = dx - dy
    
    while true {
        if x0 >= 0, y0 >= 0 {
            points.append(CGPoint(x: x0, y: y0))
        }
        if x0 == x1, y0 == y1 {
            break
        }
        let e2 = err * 2
        if e2 > -dy {
            err -= dy
            x0 += sx
        }
        if e2 < dx {
            err += dx
            y0 += sy
        }
    }
    
    return points
}

// 丸め処理で、小数点以下を切り捨てる処理
func getPointsB(p0: CGPoint, p1: CGPoint) -> [CGPoint] {
    var points = [CGPoint]()
    var x0 = p0.x.rounded(.down)
    var y0 = p0.y.rounded(.down)
    let x1 = p1.x.rounded(.down)
    let y1 = p1.y.rounded(.down)
    let dx = abs(p1.x - p0.x)
    let dy = abs(p1.y - p0.y)
    let sx = (p1.x > p0.x) ? 1.0 : -1.0
    let sy = (p1.y > p0.y) ? 1.0 : -1.0
    var err = dx - dy
    
    while true {
        if x0 >= 0, y0 >= 0 {
            points.append(CGPoint(x: x0, y: y0))
        }
        if x0 == x1, y0 == y1 {
            break
        }
        let e2 = err * 2
        if e2 > -dy {
            err -= dy
            x0 += sx
        }
        if e2 < dx {
            err += dx
            y0 += sy
        }
    }
    
    return points
}

// 処理時間の比較
let startTime = Date()
let points = getPointsA(p0: CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0), p1: CGPoint(x: 5000.3, y: 10000.7))
let interval = -startTime.timeIntervalSinceNow
print(interval)

let startTime2 = Date()
let points2 = getPointsB(p0: CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0), p1: CGPoint(x: 5000.3, y: 10000.7))
let interval2 = -startTime2.timeIntervalSinceNow
print(interval2)

// 結果
// 0.00038504600524902344
// 0.00018894672393798828
```

型変換のコストがかからない分、時間が短いということだと思われます。

Comment: ありがとうございます！早速実装してみたいと思います。ただ、結果の違いが気にはなるところなので、なんともいえないところです。

Comment: ところで、ご質問で提示された関数`getPoints(p0, p1)`は、引数にある値を与えると、無限ループになるようです。`let points = getPoints(p0: CGPoint(x: 5.7, y: 5.1), p1: CGPoint(x: 10.6, y: 10.1))`を実行してみてください。質問の地点から遡って、抜本的な書き直しが必要ではないでしょうか？